# Activity com.act.hyd.app.EmtyActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@416e8bb8 that was originally added here

Tags: android

i am getting error.

```
Activity com.act.hyd.app.EmtyActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@416e8bb8 that was originally added here
```

in a splash screen I will check version code of app. If it is not suitable version then show an `AlertDialog`. But I am getting the above error.how to solve it.

```
public void incorrectMessages(){


           AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);

                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, close
                            // current activity
                            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                            startActivity(browserIntent);
                        }
                      })
                    .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, just close
                            // the dialog box and do nothing
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    // create alert dialog
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                    // show it
                    alertDialog.show();




                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dear ACT Customer your App looks old version .Please upgrade from Playstore ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 onRestart();
             }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Activity has leaked window that was originally added](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added)

Comment: Post the source code of the activity, I think that you could be calling the alert more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just before you go to the new Activity, you need to close the dialog of the current activity.

```
.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, close
                            // current activity
                            // --------------------------
                            // here you need to dismiss the dialog
                             dialog.dismiss();
                            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                            startActivity(browserIntent);

                        }
                      })
```

otherwise the dialog window will be leaked.

good luck

Answer (score 1):

You need to call

`alertDialogBuilder.dismiss()`

before you finish the Activty.

Answer (score 0):

`setNegativeButton` function you are have called  `dialog.dismiss();` but you have not dismissed your dialogbox on `setPositiveButton` , so you also need to dismiss your dialog box in `setPositiveButton` function.

**OR**

you can also use `onDestroy()`. write below function on your activity

```
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();

  if(dialog !=null)
  {
    dialog.dismiss();
  }
}
```